# Acces component data from service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form in my component that I'm using with reactive form and I'd like to access this form trough my service.

So let's say:

```
const id = MyComponent.id
```

and in my component:

```
@Output: public id: number = 7;
```

Comment: It sounds like you're approaching component/service communication slightly incorrectly. Your component needs to send its data TO the service (generally via a method).

Comment: Well my problem is that I have a component that will call get function from the service and the service need to get data from 3 other components combine it and send it to the component calling the service. I guess I'll try to approach this a different way.

Comment: I think it's the direction of your thought that isn't quite right. Services don't ask for stuff from components. Your components all need to tell the service when their values change if you want to keep the architecture you have. You can use the `valueChanges` Observables in each control to keep calling the service method and updating its data. You can also use the Subject-as-a-Service suggestion in @Almaniac's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of services as a space that declares and instantiates external calls like API calls.
I also use services as a "catch-all".
Indeed, in Angular, when you define a service in the constructor of your component, it will remain open throughout the session.

So you have several ways to pass data.
You can do it in a static way but also in a dynamic way allowing to monitor events.

For example:

**in Service**

```
export class MyService {
myString: string = '';

constructor(){ }

getMyString(): String{ return this.myString; }

    setMyString(newVal: string){
        this.myString = newVal;
    }
}
```

**In component**

```
export class MyComponent implements onInit {  
myString = undefined;  
constructor(myService: MyService ){} 
    ngOnInit(){ 
        this.myString = this.myService.getMyString();
    } 
}
```

Otherwise there is another method, which allows you to check when you have a value change.
For this I use BehaviorSubject.
More expensive in resources, but allow to be subscribed, but you have to think to unsubscribe them in the ngOnDestroy.

So to do this in the service :

**in Service**

```
export class MyService {
myString: behaviorSubject= new behaviorSubject('');

constructor(){ }

getMyString(): Observable{ return this.myString.asObservable(); }

    setMyString(newVal: string){
        this.myString.next(newVal);
    }
}
```

**in component**

```
export class MyComponent implements onInit {
myString;
 constructor(myService: MyService ){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.myService.getMyString().subscribe((data)=>myString=data);
    }
}
```

I hope these explanations will help you.
I gave you an example with String but of course this is only a sample